# Can sqlx infer a non-NULL output column for a JOIN query?

Tags: postgresql, rust-sqlx

For two postgresql tables, `a` and `b` with non-null columns

```rust
struct MyStruct {
  id: i32,
  name: String,
}

sqlx::query_as!(MyStruct, r"
  SELECT a.id, b.name
  FROM a
  INNER JOIN b on a.id = b.a
")
```

results in errors like the following

```
mismatched types
expected type i32
   found enum std::option::Option<i32> rustcE0308
macros.rs(552, 9): Actual error occurred here
macros.rs(552, 9): Error originated from macro call here
```

I can force sqlx to mark the columns as non-null via the [`foo as "foo!"`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/macro.query.html#force-not-null) syntax, but I'd rather not.

```rust
sqlx::query_as!(MyStruct, r#"
  SELECT a.id as "id!", b.name as "name!"
  FROM a
  INNER JOIN b on a.id = b.a
"#)
```

In [the sqlx documentation](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/macro.query.html#nullability-output-columns) it says

> In most cases, the database engine can tell us whether or not a column
> may be NULL, and the query!() macro adjusts the field types of the
> returned struct accordingly.
>
> For Postgres, this only works for columns which come directly from
> actual tables, as the implementation will need to query the table
> metadata to find if a given column has a NOT NULL constraint. Columns
> that do not have a NOT NULL constraint or are the result of an
> expression are assumed to be nullable and so Option is used instead
> of T.

Does a `JOIN` count as an expression that would prevent the database engine from inferring non-nullability? Am I missing something about sqlx that would enable it to correctly infer that those columns cannot be null?